# Centering Across Selection Using EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

If you select adjacent cells in excel and click 'Format Cells', within the alignment tab you can set text alignment to 'Center Across Selection'.

Is there a way to apply this programatically using EPPlus? I searched on their official documentation and couldn't find anything. If there is no way to apply this through EPPlus, what is the best alternative?

The use case is that I need to traverse through cells in one particular row in excel and turn duplicate entries into one entry centered across the cells. The logic I had in mind is to delete the content in all bar the first cell and then center across a selection of all the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EPPlus supports this using `CenterContinuous` like this:

```
ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.CenterContinuous;
```

Comment: `worksheet.Cells[3, start, 3, end].Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.CenterContinuous;` I've stepped through my code and this line executes with start equal to 4 and end equal to 5, yet the text is not centered across 3,4 and 3,5, it is instead only centered over 3,4. Any ideas?

Comment: @ANON  Humm..are you trying to do a `.Merge = true` maybe?  Not 100% sure what you are trying to do so post a picture maybe.

Comment: I've just realised what's been happening - in deleting the values in the other cells I was just putting an empty string in there, but I've just read that having an empty string in a cell will mess up centering across selections. So placing 'null' into the cells seems to have fixed it.